# Possible reasons for javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, cryptography, checksum

I am using amazon S3 to store files. While storing, I am encrypting the stream on the fly. Again on download, I decrypt the stream on the fly. This set up is working very well but occasionally I am getting following exceptions -

**javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher**

What could be possible reasons for this error to happen. Is corruption of data during upload/download is one of the possibilities? If yes, will this happen only when padding bytes are corrupted or any of the bytes in file got corrupted?

[EDIT] But the strange thing is that the file size stored in S3 is proper, it's not like only half of the file got stored.

Comment: Do you only get this padding exception, or do you get others as well (illegal padding exceptions)?

Comment: Yes, I am getting padding exceptions as well - java.io.IOException: Error closing stream: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Its most likely that you receive partial files. You should be able to check if the connection was aborted before completion. To be sure you get the full, unchanged file, add a (H)MAC or use a cipher mode with integrity validation (e.g. GCM).

[EDIT]: No, this *particular* decryption exception should only happen when the full file is not available, not when the file itself is currupted. Better check the file handling upon receiving (forgetting to close stream or delete partial files).

Comment: Are you sure your source is adding padding?  Are you sure you are using the same padding as your source?  Mismatched padding can cause this problem.

Comment: @Rossum, why are you replying on my answer? It seems that the asker is encrypting decrypting by himself as well...

Comment: Yes I am encrypting during put and decrypting while downloading and taking care of padding. This issue is happening only once in a thousand tries, otherwise it succeeds.

Comment: It's most likely that not the reading part goes wrong, it is more likely that for some reason or another the full file is not written (server error, bad handling of disconnects), or that the file is read before the write process completes.

Comment: @owlstead I agree that its not the get part which is going wrong because I tried multiple get retries on the problematic files and always got the same exception.